# Check inventory for item

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have been working on a command called "game", however for this command you need a tablet in your inventory. To wrap it up, my question is: **How can you make it that the bot checks if the item (tablet) is in your inventory?** I have been struggling with this for the past 3 hours, I have tried to change the code multiple times, like changing the JSON file to have an extra unique rarity and check with that rarity if the item is there, however this had no effect either. I get no errors but also no succes, when I run the command nothing happens, no errors, nothing happens in the server. Any help would be appreciated!

The command:

```
@client.command()
async def game(ctx):

    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author
    users = await get_bank_data()

    try:
        bag = users[str(user.id)]["bag"]
    except:
        bag = []

    if bag.contains("tablet"):
        await ctx.send("More coding. . .")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Buy a tablet!")
```

The JSON file:

```
{"703287162640007278": {"wallet": 431, "bank": 534404, "bag": [{"item": "milk", "amount": 2}, {"item": "Golden Coin", "amount": 1}, {"item": "alarm", "amount": 1}, {"item": "tablet", "amount": 1}, {"item": "pistol", "amount": 1}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `bag` is list of dicts, i.e. you already accessed key `'bag'` from JSON file:

```
"bag": [{"item": "milk", "amount": 2}, {"item": "Golden Coin", "amount": 1}, {"item": "alarm", "amount": 1}, {"item": "tablet", "amount": 1}, {"item": "pistol", "amount": 1}]
```

You need to check if any if in any of these dicts there is key `item` with value `tablet`. So:

`if any(element['item'] == 'tablet' for element in bag):`

EDIT:
try something like this:

```
bag = users[str(user.id)].get("bag")
print(bag)

# it should print the bag or None
# [{"item": "milk", "amount": 2}, {"item": "Golden Coin", "amount": 1},
# {"item": "alarm", "amount": 1}, {"item": "tablet", "amount": 1}, 
#  {"item": "pistol", "amount": 1}]

if bag:
    if any(element['item'] == 'tablet' and element['amount'] > 0
           for element in bag):
        # do something if tablet in bag
    else:
        # no tablet in bag
else:
    # do something is there is no bag
```

demo:

```
bag = [{"item": "milk", "amount": 2}, {"item": "Golden Coin", "amount": 1},
       {"item": "alarm", "amount": 1}, {"item": "tablet", "amount": 1}, 
       {"item": "pistol", "amount": 1}]

if bag:
    if any(element['item'] == 'tablet' and element['amount'] > 0
           for element in bag):
        print('tablet found')
    else:
        print('no tablet in the bag')
else:
    print('no bag')
```

output:

```
tablet found
```

Comment: Thank you! This answered the main problem, however it still has the problem if  'amount' = 0, the item is still there but you have none purchased. But thank you again for the main problem! I'll try to struggle with the amount now :)

Comment: just add `and element['amount'] > 0` in the condition

Comment: also instead of list of dicts, it may be better to refactor it as simple dict, e.g. `'bag':{'milk;:2, 'tablet':1...}`. It will simplify access enormously.

Comment: yeah, I came up with the same solution however it gives me now no errors and no output in the server again. I'm confused since the code looks good

Comment: Remove the blank try except and check what you get for bag

Comment: I already tried that, still the same, no errors, no output

Comment: Well, what you get when you print bag?

Comment: Nothing, the console just shows nothing, I tried moving the print around a little, when I do it under the if statement it doesn't print anything, if I put it under the bag = users.. it just gets me the bag

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I'll try to use these kinds of codes to make it easier for myself! Thanks again!